# Throttle stream without buffering

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have some toast messages that I'd like to throttle. I tried using buffer but then I get a bunch of messages in an array when what I'd really like is for the messages to simply stay in the stream until I ask for them. What I ended up doing was zipping my message stream with an interval stream

```
var messageStream = Rx.Observable.FromEvent(..., 'click');
var intervalStream = Rx.Observable.interval(5000);
messageStream.Zip(intervalStream, (x,_)=>x).subscribe(showToast(x));
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [controlled](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/controlled.md). It enables you to queue values, waiting for you to `.request(x)` x values. To use with care, as this means memory will be used to buffer the values and memory is not infinite. This could also be a good reading : [backpressure](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/backpressure.md)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using buffer, followed by a flatMap to unwind the array:

```
var messageStream = Rx.Observable.FromEvent(..., 'click');
var intervalStream = Rx.Observable.interval(5000);
messageStream
    .buffer(intervalStream)
    .flatMap( function (x) {
        return Rx.Observable.from(x)
    })
    .subscribe( function  (x) { 
        showToast(x) 
    })
```

[Example here on jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/jkennaly/zpc9foop/)